# signal light showing phone charge state

Tags: telephony, smart-home

I have a couple of cordless landline phones with docking stations. Whenever a docking station is unoccupied, I want some sort of signal lamp to light up, until the phone is returned to the cradle. When the phone is in the cradle, the lamp should be off.

I am not sure whether such a thing even exists.
But this seems like such a common problem. This is for a senior person, phones are often left to discharge.

The phones are DECT phones by Siemens; I believe with unstandardized cradles.

So I am looking for either some sort of sensor that can be taped to the cradle to detect whether a phone is present; or perhaps some sort of DECT device that can monitor the charging state of nearby phones?

so I am looking for some sort of device:
    - light on, when a nearby phone is not in cradle
    - light off, when phone is in cradle
    - ideally not much assembly required
    - as maintenance free as possible
    - very optional: some sort of remote monitoring via internet

I fear that nothing like this exists, all my searches turned up empty so far. The closest I could think is some sort of Arduino & sensor assembly, but I have no experience with that.

Comment: Here's a tutorial about using [magnetic field sensors with an Arduino](https://www.element14.com/community/community/arduino/blog/2015/04/24/using-magnetic-sensors-to-make-kinematics-experiments), you could tape or glue a magnet to the phone and put a sensor in the cradle. You could also replace the Arduino with a Raspberry Pi for remote access. I'm on the fence whether this question is on-topic though. If you go with a DIY approach, it would be on-topic to ask for a shopping list to build your design. Another stack exchange site may be more suited to asking for help with designing it though.

Comment: Thanks, the DIY approach is a last resort for me, I doubt I will have the free time and patience for that in the near future. For now I am really hoping for a piece of hardware that could do this on its own. I apologize if this is off topic, I admit I am a little uncertain on what sort of hardware may be recommended *here*, or rather on another stackexchange site.

Comment: I'm fairly certain a consumer device like you're imagining doesn't exist, but I don't have enough confidence to post that as an answer. This kind of feature is probably built right in to some models of phones because it seems like it would be a common problem. Maybe you should search for a phone that has this feature? At the very least, many phones can be set to beep when the battery is going low as a reminder to put it back in the charger cradle.